# Testing pre-defined callback function with Mocha.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, asynchronous, mocha.js

I am trying to write a test for the following function.

```
function services(api){
    request(`${api}?action=services`, function(err, res, body) {
        if (!err && res.statusCode === 200){
            var resJson = JSON.parse(body);
            var numberOfServices = resJson.length;
            console.log("Service called: services");
            console.log("-----------");
            for (i = 0; i < numberOfServices; i++){
                console.log("Service ID: " + resJson[i].service);
                console.log("Service Name: " + resJson[i].name);
                console.log("-----------");
            }
            return resJson;
        }
    }); 
}
```

The test is checking to see if the function returns an object. `resJson` is the object being returned and tested.

Below is the test case written using Mocha.js and Chai.js assertion library.

```
var chai = require('chai');
var assert = chai.assert;
var sendRequest = require('../request');

describe('Test 1', function() {

    var api = 'http://instant-fans.com/api/v2';

    it('services() should return an object of services', function(done) {
        var object = sendRequest.services(api);
        assert.isObject(object);
    });

});
```

However, when I run the test it fails with the following console output. Saying that `resJson` is undefined. I'm guessing that Mocha is trying to assert that `resJson` is an object BEFORE the function `services()` returns the object, but I am not sure how to resolve this.

```
 Test 1
    1) services() should return an object of services

 0 passing (27ms)
 1 failing

  1) Test 1 services() should return an object of services:
     AssertionError: expected undefined to be an object
      at Function.assert.isObject (node_modules/chai/lib/chai/interface/assert.js:555:35)
      at Context.<anonymous> (test/requestTest.js:11:16)
```

I have tried to search this online, I have seen people resolve this using `done()` method. However in my case that does not work due to the fact I am using a callback inside my `services()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you read this [**question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call/14220323#14220323) concerning usage of asynchronous functions

---

You can't assign asynchronous function call to variable just as you do in `var object = sendRequest.services(api)`. You need to use `callback`, which should be added as a parameter to `services` function

```
function services(api, callback){
    // your logic here
}
```

And instead performing `return resJson` you can call `callback(resJson)` in the `services` function. Then, in your test, you need to call the `services` with second parameter being a `function(result)`

```
sendRequest.services(api, function(result){
    assert.isObject(result);
});
```

**EDIT**

This is how your `services` function should look like

```
function services(api, callback){
    request(`${api}?action=services`, function(err, res, body) {
        if (!err && res.statusCode === 200){
            var resJson = JSON.parse(body);
            var numberOfServices = resJson.length;
            console.log("Service called: services");
            console.log("-----------");
            for (i = 0; i < numberOfServices; i++){
                console.log("Service ID: " + resJson[i].service);
                console.log("Service Name: " + resJson[i].name);
                console.log("-----------");
            }
            callback(resJson);
        }
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Am I going to need to make changes to the `services()` function?

Comment: Yes, as I said, instead doing `return resJson` you should do `callback(resJson)`. That will ensure you that the assertion is done. I edited the answer with updated `services` function

Comment: Ah that's the first time i've come across that, thank-you! :)

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks like it is doing an asynchronous request `sendRequest.services(api);`

What you need to do is handle the `done()` callback that is made available in the mocha test: `it('services() should return an object of services', function(done) {})`

What you need to do is re-write your `services` function because it is incorrect. You cannot return from an asynchronous function, async functions are generally I/O based and do not block the main Nodejs thread. In order for your main thread to access the value you have to pass in a callback function that will be executed once the value is made available.

```
function services(api, cb){
    request(`${api}?action=services`, function(err, res, body) {
        var resJson;
        if (!err && res.statusCode === 200){
            resJson = JSON.parse(body);
            var numberOfServices = resJson.length;
            console.log("Service called: services");
            console.log("-----------");
            for (i = 0; i < numberOfServices; i++){
                console.log("Service ID: " + resJson[i].service);
                console.log("Service Name: " + resJson[i].name);
                console.log("-----------");
            }
        }
        if (cb) {
            cb(err, resJson);
        }
    }); 
}
```

And rewrite your test like so:

```
describe('Test 1', function() {
    var api = 'http://instant-fans.com/api/v2';

    it('services() should return an object of services', function(done) {
        sendRequest.services(api, function(resJson) {
            assert.isObject(resJson);
            done();
        });
    });

});
```

I would go even further and pass in the error to the callback function (this is common practice in nodejs):

```
cb(err, resJson);
```

And your test can print the error for better debugging:

```
sendRequest.services(api, function(err, resJson) {
    if (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
    assert.isObject(resJson);
    done();
});
```